# MS Access form_current() firing multiple times

Tags: ms-access, forms, ms-access-2003

I have a form with two subforms (on separate tab pages). It's an MDB project in Access
2003.

When it initially opens, Form_Current on the active subform fires once, as
it should.

But when you move to another record (ie. from the main form), it fires
Form_Current on the active subform 4 times. Then subsequent record-moves
result in Form_Current firing 2 times. This is a pain, because the subforms
have a lot of fields that get moved and/or hidden and so it jumps around for
every Form_Current, not to mention being slow.

I am opening the form with a filter via DoCmd.OpenForm (actually it sends
the filter in via OpenArgs). FilterOn is only set once, in Form_Open on the
main form, never in the subforms. Form_Current is not called explicitly
anywhere else in the code.

When I look at the call stack when Form_Current fires moving the first time,
it looks like:

```
my_subform.Form_Current
[<Debug Window>]
my_subform.Form_Current
```

So it seems like something in Form_Current is triggering another
Form_Current event. But only on the first record move.

The code in Form_Current is somewhat complex, involving custom classes and
event callbacks, but generally does not touch the table data. The only thing I
can think might be triggering a Form_Current is that it checks OldValue on
form controls - could this be causing it?

Or anything else come to mind?

Thanks.

Eric

Comment: This is a known issue that can't be worked around -- the OnCurrent event of a subform always first twice. There's nothing you can do about it except to use a counter to prevent the code from firing a second time.

Answer (score 2):

As TheAceMan1 once noted, "The only thing you have to watch out for with the On Current event is recursion! That is  ... code in the event that causes the event to retrigger. Like moving to another record within the code. Other than that ... the event can be as hefty as required."  I have found Current to be horribly twitchy.  That said, it is sometimes the only place to put your code.

You may be aware that events for sub-forms trigger before those for the parent form.  This is certainly true for Load, and maybe for Current as well.

I can only suggest step-by-step trouble-shooting; comment out parts, check functioning, and work it out.  Of course you can always post a heap more code for us to see.

Comment: Thanks - it may be related to subform current triggering before parent form, then again on setting focus to subform, or something. Wish I had the time to track it down.  For the moment I think the users can manage with editing one record at a time.